# Update text in Angular Toastr

Tags: angular, typescript, toastr

I would like to change the `toastr` text already displayed.

I am using the following code to create and trying to update the existing text.

```
  if (this.toastr.currentlyActive > 0) {
    this.toastr.toasts.find(toast => toast.toastId == 1).message = "Tempo em Atendimento: " + tempoAtendimento;
  } else {
    this.toastr.info("Tempo em Atendimento: " + tempoAtendimento, "", { timeOut: 0, extendedTimeOut: 0 });
  }
```

I do not receive error message, however, the text is not changed! Any tips?

[image]

I am using:
https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/
Versão:
10.1.0

Comment: @Alessandro, please mention what package have you used ?, which things you have tried and and then add what issue you are facing.  In your question you have not added complete code, which Toastr package you are using

Comment: `this.toastr.toasts.find(toast => toast.toastId == 1)` will return `ActiveToast` object and hanging the `message` on the `ActiveToast` object would not effect the component itself, to do that you'll have to modify the message attribute on the component itself, try doing `this.toastr.toasts.find(toast => toast.toastId == 1).toastRef.componentInstance.message = "new message"`

Comment: @Minato That's right, problem solved!

Comment: I'll put it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.toastr.toasts.find(toast => toast.toastId == 1)
```

will return `ActiveToast` object and changing the `message` property on the `ActiveToast` object would not effect the component itself.

To change the message on the displayed component you need reference to the component object. So that you could update the `message` property directly on the component itself. You can easily get the reference to the instance of the component from the `ActiveToast` object by

```
let _componentInstance = this.toastr.toasts.find(toast => toast.toastId == 1).toastRef.componentInstance
```

then simply modify the `message` property on `_componentInstance` to whatever you want like.

```
_componentInstance.message = "new message"
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @Minato his answer...

When you create a toastr message, an instance of the `ActiveToast` is returned. If you store that in a variable you won't have to search for it by id.

```
const toast: ActiveToast = this.toastrService.success('My toastr message');
const componentInstance: Toast = toast.toastRef.componentInstance;
setTimeout(
  () => toastComponent.message = 'My changed message', 3000
);
```